# Use Microsoft Bookings page with pre-filled fields

Tags: office365

I'm setting up Microsoft Bookings and I'm going to publish my booking page on my website showing it in an `iframe`. I want to improve the customer experience to users already logged in on my website and when I open the published Microsoft Bookings page I want to pre-fill the fields for the user. I tried adding them via the URL:

`https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/mycompany@company.com/bookings/?Name=Paul&customerPhoner=1234&f14e30d1-0a96-4ad3-bc5e-41fake1e79=56789`

Using Javascript to fill the fields seems a dead-end too since it's cross-origin.

The last one is a custom field. Unfortunately this will give an error (Bad request). Is there any way to fill in the default values for the fields? I'm also open to options using other options then via the querystring.